# Expo ejected application

Tags: react-native, expo, mobile-development

I've created an application with CRNA. After some time I ejected it with "yarn eject" to have a possibility to configure native modules. 
So now I have a question. Is there any possibility to use "exp publish"?

Before ejecting I used expo xde to publish my applications and run them via expo client. 
Do I have the same functionality with the ejected application? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [official docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/detach#6-distribute-your-app):

> Publishing your JS from XDE/exp will still work. Users of your app will get the new JS on their devices as soon as they reload their app; you don't need to rebuild your native code if it has not changed.

If you make native code changes, update your native version number so that users with old native versions will not get the update (as that will result in crash if you call newly added native functions), until it's updated from App Store/Google Play (with your new build).

Comment: Hello.. I have a question that If i made a project through expo start and then at the middle I require some codes to be run on android and iOS folders. Then what to do ? And after that will the expo modules work again? And after changing into the iOS and android I again want to go to expo and start development again. Then what to do?